# Python error when importing image_to_string from tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I recently used tesseract OCR with python and I kept getting an error when I was trying to import `image_to_string` from tesseract.

Code causing the problem:

```
# Perform OCR using tesseract-ocr library
from tesseract import image_to_string
image = Image.open('input-NEAREST.tif')
print image_to_string(image)
```

Error caused by above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
file "./captcha.py", line 52, in <module>  
from tesseract import image_to_string  
ImportError: cannot import name image_to_string
```

I've verified that the tesseract module is installed:

```
digital_alchemy@roaming-gnome /home $ pydoc modules | grep 'tesseract'
Hdf5StubImagePlugin _tesseract          gzip                sipconfig
ORBit               cairo               mako                tesseract
```

I believe that I've grabbed all the required packages but unfortunately I'm just stuck at this point.  It appears that the function is not in the module.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: try "import tesseract.image_to_string", or even just "import tesseract".

Comment: I think you have the wrong python bindings... What do you have in `vars(tesseract)`?

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility that seems to have worked for me is to modify pytesseract so that instead of import Image it has from PIL import Image

Code that works in PyCharm after modifying pytesseract:

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(r'C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\dashboard-test.jpeg')
print(im)

print(image_to_string(im))
```

Pytesseract I installed via the package management built into PyCharm

Comment: I get an error saying - OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
In File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child

Comment: @C.R.Sharat Yes, a long time ago. I don't remember what solved it. If it helps I am using `PIL==1.1.7
pytesseract==0.1.6
Pillow==2.9.0` and I have installed `sudo apt-get install python-opencv` also

Comment: apt-get install tesseract-ocr # This may solve this issue, @C.R.Sharat

Answer (score 1):

Is your syntax correct for the module you have installed? That `image_to_string` functions looks like it is from PyTesser per the usage example on this page:
https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/

Your import looks like it is for python-tesseract which has a more complicated usage example listed:
https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/

Answer (score 1):

For windows followed below steps

```
pip3 install pytesseract 
pip3 install pillow
```

Installation of tessaract-ocr is also required
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki
otherwise you will get an error Tessract is not on path

Python code

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

print ( image_to_string(Image.open('test.tif'),lang='eng')  )
```

Answer (score 0):

what works for me:

after I install the pytesseract form [tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.02-20180621.exe](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)
I add the line 
`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"`
and use the code form the above this is all the code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
im=Image.open("C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\ro\\capt.png")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im,lang='eng'))
```

I am using windows 10 with PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.3 x64

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
im=Image.open(r"C:\Users\path\1_python-ocr.jpg")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im,lang='eng'))
```